# How does the Polymer binding works on array?

Tags: arrays, data-binding, polymer, web-component

Let's consider the following code:

```
  <dom-module id="foo-bar">
  <template>
    <h2>Example 1</h2>
    <button on-tap="tap1">Tap 1</button> | <button on-tap="tap2">Tap 2</button> 
    <hr>
    <ul>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{myarray}}">
        <li>{{index}}: {{item.title}}</li>
      </template>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    {{myarray}}
    <hr>
    <h2>Example 1</h2>
    <button on-tap="tap3">Tap 3</button>
    <hr>
    <ul>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{myarray2}}">
        <li>{{index}}: {{item.title}}</li>
      </template>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    {{myarray2}}
    <hr>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'foo-bar',
      properties: {
        myarray: {
          type: Array,
          value: [null, null],
          notify: true
        },
        myarray2: {
          type: Array,
          value: [{title: 'a'}, {title: 'b'}],
          notify: true
        }
      },
      tap1: function() {
        this.myarray = [{title: 'Hello'}, {title: 'World'}];
      },
      tap2: function() {
        this.set('myarray.0', {title: 'Hello'});
        this.set('myarray.1', {title: 'World'});
      },
      tap3: function() {
        this.set('myarray2.0', {title: 'Hello'});
        this.set('myarray2.1', {title: 'World'});
      }
    })
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

The principle is to display the content of the array (`myarray`) and updates the display whenever its content changes.

When I click on `Tap 1` button, as the array is redefined completely, everything works as expected.

According to the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#array-binding), Polymer is not able to detect a modification within the array itself, and they recommend to use the `this.set(...)` method. That's what I did in the `tap2` function of my code:

```
  tap2: function() {
    this.set('myarray.0', {title: 'Hello'});
    this.set('myarray.1', {title: 'World'});
  }
```

However, when I click on the `Tap 2` button, even if the array is correctly updated in the code (I can see it with a `console.log`), the list (in `<ul></ul>`) is not set correctly, as I get:

> - 0: World
> - 1:

(the first index display the value of the second element of the aray) and the full display of the array (in `{{myarray}}`) does not print anything.

Another scenario, `Tap3`, behaves correctly, since I've initialized an array (`myarray2`) with objects directly.

I've also made another test (not on Plunker), where `myarray` is initialized with `[]` (and not `[null, null]`). In that case, the list (`<ul></ul>`) is always empty, before or after the click on the button.

So finally, my question is to understand how the double binding works on the array content, and why the second case (`Tap 2`) happens?

Thanks

([Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZRv606oy1Y5pX2xLRh8R))

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `dom-repeat` has problems with non unique primitives (see this [issue](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1913)). The elements need to have a unique identity. As a workaround define your array like this:

```
myarray: {
  type: Array,
  value: function() { return [{}, {}];},
  notify: true
},
```

This will fix the issue (see modified [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PsGzzTrzdyDxfSsM6sRG?p=preview))

As a sidenote: For `Arrays` and `Object` properties, make sure to use a `function` to return the default `value` otherwise you will run into issues (basically sharing the value among all instances of that element)